# boost::spirit::karma semantic action assignment error

Tags: c++, boost, placeholder, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

I'm trying to set karmas generator-value by a semantic action, however, it won't compile. I can't find the reson why, as I'm quite sure I use it as explained in the documentation. As I'm new to karma it's most likely I did some rookie mistake. A minimal example:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma_int.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma_generate.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> out(s);
    boost::spirit::karma::generate(out,karma::int_[karma::_1=2]); //won't compile
    //boost::spirit::karma::generate(out,karma::int_,2); this compiles and works
    std::cout<<s;
}
```

results in the comipler error:

```
 error: no viable overloaded '='
```

I'm using g++ 4.6.3 and boost 1.48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some headers to include. You can either use:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
```

that includes the operators needed for this to work, or:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
```

that includes everything about Boost.Phoenix. [On LWS.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2vX6ST%241)